# How does comment notification work?

Tags: support, comments, notifications, comment-replies

Where is a good description of how comment notification (e.g. @ripper234) works?

Does it work the same on Stack Exchange?

Comment: This question is favorited by one, yet it had -2 in score before I voted it up ... weird :P What's wrong with this question anyway?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye - Meta works in mysterious ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/

One addition since then, comments now support markdown links in the form

`[example](http://example.com)`